# How to relate unrelated microdata schema types?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, rich-snippets

I'm trying to show my customers where the nearest `CivilStructure` is (e.g. railway station or airport) to a particular `Product` sold by an `Organsization`.

Here is an example of what I mean

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name"> Name of product </h1>
  <p itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"> Name of company selling product </p>
  <ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CivicStructure">
    <li itemprop="name">Name of railway station</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`Product` has a property of brand which can then be used to provide information on an `Organization` selling that product. However, I can't find an `itemprop` property within `Product` or `Organization` to link a `CivilStructure` to the `Organization`. Its basically a related location but I'm struggling to understand how to mark it up correctly. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Could you describe in which way the location is related to the product? Is the product offered there?

Comment: @unor no, the product itself is not offered there. I'm trying to tell people where the nearest bus stop, railway stop etc is to the place where the product is offered. So the location is related to the organisation rather than the product